Can we find a function $y=f(x)$ such that $a+b=f(a)f(b)$?

Can we find a function $y=f(x)$ such that $a+b=f(a)f(b)$?
For example, $3+2=5$, so $f(3)f(2)=5$; $78+1=79$, so $f(78)f(1)=79$.
How can we find such a function?
The wider the range of values of the independent variable, the better, and it is best if the domain is all complex numbers.


What you get when you put $b=0$?

No. $$f(2)f(3)=2+3=5,f(2)f(4)=2+4=6\implies \frac{f(3)}{f(4)}=\frac{5}{6}$$
$$f(4)f(3)=4+3=7,f(4)f(4)=4+4=8\implies \frac{f(3)}{f(4)}=\frac{7}{8}$$
Contradiction here.

Thanks, it is very useful.
